# Matching a string using a javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
name=cvbb&source=Mamma+Mia&startdate=2014-03-24
```

The following regex matches till startdate

```
(source=.*(startdate))
```

How do I match the string till the '&' after Mia?

UPDATE:

name=cvbb&source=Mamma+Mia&startdate=2014-03-24&date=2014-04-24

I want the match to occur until the occurrence of the & right after Mia

Comment: Are you planning to parse that string later?

Comment: yes i intend to do so

Comment: For you information regular expressions engines are usually greedy - meaning they try to match as much as they can according to the regex. This is the reason the & is matched as well.

Comment: @Paulie what does `the string till the '&' after Mia` look like? Please provide the portion of the string you want to get.

Comment: @Paulie Is this what you're trying to get? ➔  `name=cvbb&source=Mamma+Mia`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these things are always in the same order, `(name=.*&)` ought to do it.

Comment: If you don't want to include the &, then use `(name=[^&]*)`.

Comment: how can i further exclude name from the match? So as to just match cvbb?

Comment: /[^name]*=[^&]*/ matches =cvbb. How to I exclude = from the match?

Comment: As in, you don't want the "=" in the returned text, or the string no longer includes an "=" and is therefore failing to match?

Comment: I don't want = in the returned text.

Comment: Try this: `(?<=name=)[^&]*`

Comment: that gives a null match

Comment: Try this: `'name=cvbb&source=Mamma+Mia&startdate=2014-03-24'.split('').reverse().join('').match(/[^&]*(?==eman)/);`

You'll have to reverse the output text, though - done by `"string".split('').reverse().join('')`.

Comment: could i just strip the '=' after matching with the regex? res = res.replace('=',''); after executing the regex isn't eliminating the '=' character

Comment: Well, since the `=` is always first, you could just do something like:

    var x="string";
    x=substring(1,x.length-1);

Comment: The = seems to be creating a conflict here so that isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Since [you are planning to parse the data later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125237/matching-a-string-using-a-javascript-regex/23125309#comment35354180_23125237), I would recommend getting a key-value pair data, like this

```
var data = "name=cvbb&source=Mamma+Mia&startdate=2014-03-24";
console.log(data.split("&").reduce(function(result, currentItem) {
    var splitted = currentItem.split("=");
    result[splitted[0]] = splitted[1];
    return result;
}, {}));
```

**Output**

```
{ name: 'cvbb', source: 'Mamma+Mia', startdate: '2014-03-24' }
```

If you want to ignore `startdate` alone, then you can include a condition like this

```
    var splitted = currentItem.split("=");
    if (splitted[0] !== "startdate") {
        result[splitted[0]] = splitted[1];
    }
    return result;
```

Then the result will be

```
{ name: 'cvbb', source: 'Mamma+Mia' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"name=cvbb&source=Mamma+Mia&startdate=2014-03-24".match(/source=([^&]+)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regexp `/.*&/` will match till the last `&`.

Updated regexp:

```
/name=.*&source=[^&]*/
```

will give `name=cvbb&source=Mamma+Mia` if the string begins with `name` and `source` follows after it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: javascript object]

**Javascript:**

See live demo: <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/8Vq6G/)**</kbd>

```
function params_match(string) {
    var rx = /([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?/g;
    var matches = {};
    var match;
    while (match = rx.exec(string)) {
        matches[match[1]] = match[2];
    }
    return matches;
}

var st = 'name=cvbb&source=Mamma+Mia&startdate=2014-03-24';
var obj = params_match(st);
//{name: "cvbb", source: "Mamma+Mia", startdate: "2014-03-24"}
```

Inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210948/1076207

---

**Regex:**

See here: http://rubular.com/r/E6Wuejs0bA

```
/([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?/

# Match 1
# 1.    name
# 2.    cvbb
#
# Match 2
# 1.    source
# 2.    Mamma+Mia
#
# Match 3
# 1.    startdate
# 2.    2014-03-24
```